# Pass parameters between routes camel apache

Tags: java, cron, apache-camel, spring-camel

```java
from("quartz2://dailyCamelScheduler?cron=" +
          "0+0/1+*+*+*+?+*"  )
    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "ReconciliationBatchRoute", "Daily camel route called")
    .routeId("dailyCamelRoute")
    .process(new Processor() {
        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            camelCronExpression = "sftp://"
    //                + username + "@"
                      + hostAddress
                      + ":22"
                      + "/POLICE_BELGE_MUTABAKAT_"
                      + "DAILY"
    //                + "&" +
                      +"?username=" + username
                      + "&password=" + password
                      + "&fileName=" + fileName
                      + "&autoCreate=false"
                      + "&strictHostKeyChecking=no"
                      + "&preferredAuthentications=publickey,password";
            exchange.setProperty("xxx", camelCronExpression);
        }
    })
    .setProperty("typeOfRoute").constant(DocumentPolicyJobTypeEnum.DAILY)
    .to("direct:ReconciliationBatchRoute.getFileFromSFTP");
    
from("direct:ReconciliationBatchRoute.getFileFromSFTP")
    .pollEnrich()
    .simple(camelCronExpression)
    .process(new Processor() {
        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            logger.info("MutabakatLog Strat Mutabakat");
            List<String> strings = IOUtils.readLines(exchange.getIn().getBody(InputStream.class));
            logger.info("qqsize: {}", strings.size());
        }
    })
    .stop();
```

First route is daily route that scheduled for daily. When called, it will call second route to go to daily folder from SFTP. There are also another routes like monthly, weekly. So, they will have different routes with different crons like the first one. But they will call second one with prepared cron expression.

The folder is different for each one.

This is global:

```
private String camelCronExpression;
```

I also tried to put that route to exchange at first one. I also put in the beginning code.

```
exchange.setProperty("xxx", camelCronExpression);
```

I tried to get it like this: because setting to global variable of class can be not good and gave error:

```java
private String expression;

from("direct:ReconciliationBatchRoute.getFileFromSFTP")
    .process(new Processor() {
        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            expression = exchange.getProperty("xxx")
        }
    })
    .pollEnrich()
    .simple(expression) //here expression seems null
```

but I could not get the expression in .simple()

Do you think those ways are good? And how can I make it not null?

I cant get and poll at same time:

```java
from("direct:ReconciliationBatchRoute.getFileFromSFTP")
    .pollEnrich()
    .simple(camelCronExpression)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get your exchange property back by [simple language](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/languages/simple-language.html#_variables) using one of the following syntax.

- exchangeProperty.foo
- exchangeProperty[foo]
- exchangeProperty.foo.OGNL

In java DSL,

```java
from("direct:ReconciliationBatchRoute.getFileFromSFTP")
    .pollEnrich()
    .simple("${exchangeProperty.xxx}")
```

---

From [exchangeProperty language](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/languages/exchangeProperty-language.html), it might also work by

```java
from("direct:ReconciliationBatchRoute.getFileFromSFTP")
    .pollEnrich()
    .exchangeProperty("xxx")
```

Comment: How can i set to get with .simple("${exchangeProperty.xxx}") ? and in processor, can i get with This did not work by the way ` .simple("${exchangeProperty.sftpExpression}")` i can see in log but it does not poll

Comment: I cannot understand your question. BUT `.simple("${exchangeProperty.xxx}")` is using camel simple language to extract the value store in exchange property of key `xxx` which you have store it in your first route's processor `exchange.setProperty("xxx", camelCronExpression);`.